# Where to exchange money

Tags: france, exchange, south-africa

I am traveling to Europe for two weeks from South Africa and the exchange rate is really not in my favour.

Where is the best place to exchange? In South Africa or when I arrive in France?

Comment: Are you sure you need to exchange money? Consider just making an ATM withdrawal once you arrive in France. Check with your bank what fees doing so might incur; it could be a better deal than going to a currency exchange office.